# Does the global oxygen levels drop during winter months?

Tags: everyday-life, atmospheric-science, climate-science

I had a thought while I was trail walking the other day and no one could provide a clear answer.

In the winter months, most of the plants are in hibernation mode. Having lost their leaves they are bare and almost look dead. So, they are not producing Oxygen or next to little. So, that means millions of trees in the northern hemisphere are sleeping right?

Does this mean that during these months $\text {CO$_{2}$}$ levels rise globally and the other Trees and Plants closest to the equator are working harder to produce more Oxygen?

I love to understand better and love your thoughts.

Comment: ["Scientists estimate that 50-80% of the oxygen production on Earth comes from the ocean."](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/ocean-oxygen.html)

Comment: Not really a physics question.

Comment: I suppose when its snowy Winter in America, it's a Summer Christmas in Australia

Comment: There is a large seasonal variation in O2 levels. See [this Nature article](https://www.nature.com/articles/358723a0). They mostly discuss marine sources of the variation, however.

Comment: @AdilMohammed However, ~70% of the land mass is on the northern hemisphere. So it would be reasonable to expect an effect.

Comment: This effect was famously discussed in _An Inconvenient Truth_, albeit with a focus on how carbon dioxide levels, which are of course orders of magnitude lower, are affected. Even from that perspective, the effect is small.

Comment: @SebastianRiese ah you are right

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because NOt appropriate for Physics SE. Try Earth Science SE or Biology SE.

Comment: I closed it but not migrating because the OP should check for past or similar questions on those SE websites prior to posting the exact same question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/16000889.2017.1311767

I just found this link.  The answer is basically, yes.  Yes there are seasonal cycles to atmospheric oxygen exactly for the reasons (and others) that you stated.

Comment: Mauna Loa CO2 measurments are quite clearly affected by a yearly cycle as well, superimposed on the upward trend.  https://gml.noaa.gov/ccgg/trends/

Comment: Please see [this guidance about screenshots of text](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/44126) (short version: please don't). Consider an [edit] to your answer.